# gem update system fails with mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

Tags: ruby

Hello I installed Ruby with asdf from this site https://gorails.com/setup/macos/14-sonoma

After gem update --system I get this error:

```
<internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require': dlopen(/Users/andreasgerecke/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/stringio-3.1.0/lib/stringio.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/andreasgerecke/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/stringio-3.1.0/lib/stringio.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/andreasgerecke/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/stringio-3.1.0/lib/stringio.bundle' (no such file), '/Users/andreasgerecke/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/stringio-3.1.0/lib/stringio.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')) - /Users/andreasgerecke/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/stringio-3.1.0/lib/stringio.bundle (LoadError)
  from <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:78:in `initialize'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:56:in `new'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:56:in `fetcher'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:77:in `initialize'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:43:in `new'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:43:in `fetcher'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:141:in `fetch_remote_gems'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:168:in `highest_remote_name_tuple'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:233:in `rubygems_target_version'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:278:in `update_rubygems'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:99:in `execute'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command.rb:326:in `invoke_with_build_args'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:254:in `invoke_command'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:193:in `process_args'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:151:in `run'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:56:in `run'
  from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem:12:in `<main>'
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing platform (`arm64-darwin-23` in your case) and run `Bundler` again.

```
$ bundle lock --add-platform arm64-darwin-23
$ bundle install
```

Read about [`bundle platform`](https://bundler.io/v1.14/man/bundle-platform.1.html) and [supporting other platforms with `bundle lock`](https://bundler.io/v1.14/man/bundle-lock.1.html#SUPPORTING-OTHER-PLATFORMS).

Answer (score 0):

I have later installed Ruby with rbenv and get no error anymore.

Credit to [spickermann](/u/2483313) for guiding me.